# Show/hide options in django app to users based on permission

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a django app and users log in to the app and use it.
However I do not want some users to access some parts of my web application.
I do not want them to see some parts, if they do not have permission.
I tried using permission_required but it shows the tab as it comes from html.
Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use if tag in template,
{{ if request.user == **your condition }}
This will handle the permissions in the HTML.